# Formatting large XML-Files in C# (without XDocument)

Tags: c#, .net, xml, stream

I have very huge XML files that i have to format. The files can be up to 10GB big.

I couldnt find any solution that doesnt include XDocument. XDocument loads the whole file into the RAM which obviously will be problematic with a 10GB file. Especially in 32 bit systems

Writing an XML formatter from scratch that works with a stream kind of feels like reinventing the wheel to me. I cant imagine me being the first person who had to work with something like this. If possible I would like to use an existing solution.

Does anyone know anything i can work with other than writing everything myself?

Thank you

- .Net Framework 4.8
- C#8

Comment: Take a look a this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15772031/how-to-parse-very-huge-xml-files-in-c) it seems the solution offered there does not load the entire document into memory.

Comment: Have you considered using XmlReader and XmlWrite in tandem to rewrite the file out via streaming?

Comment: Use a combination of xmlReader and xml linq.  See my answer at following posting : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40456446/efficient-way-to-read-large-xml-into-dfferent-node-types-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [XmlReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreader?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) class.
This class does not load the entire document into memory, as opposed to the `XDocument` [implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42732752/4476015).